# In a State, I have date field, due to which I am getting an error saying "java.util.date is not annotated so cannot be used in serilization"

Tags: java, corda

I have a State file, Which has a date field, and in schema I have added Temporal annotation, but even though it says `java.util.date is not annotated so cannot be used in serilization` .

I have tried with  @CordaSerializable annotation for the whole state. It doesn't work.

State :

```
@CordaSerializable
public class FooState implements QueryableState {
private Date temp;
}
```

Schema:

```
@Column(name = "Issue_Date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE
private Date temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly an issue due to using `Date`. You should use `Instant`, `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` instead.

Comment: Its working, Normal date is working fine, But we can't annotate cordaSerializable over date rather we have to add it in whitelist.